# ReactJS unique key in map function problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a piano app on React . I've created a array for storing note like this :

```
const notes = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B"];
```

then I've mapped it like this :

```
<ul>
    {notes.map((note) => {
      if (note === "C") {
        return (
          <>
            <li key={note}>{note}</li>
            <li key={`${note}#`}>{note}#</li>
          </>
        );
      }
      return (
        <li key={note}>{note}</li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
```

But `ReactJS` always pop the warning about unique key in list items .
I've belived the problem is this :

```
<li key={`${note.id}#`}>{note.note}#</li>
```

But I can't quite understand why ( tried to log the key part in the console and they all look unique to me ). Can anyone explain this for me ? Thank in advance .

Comment: I'd belived I'd add the key to it  
`<li key={${note}#}>` . 
Is this the wrong way to do ?

Comment: I *completely* misread this, I have no idea what I was thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add key for parent tags.
so it should look like this:

```
<ul>
{notes.map((note) => {
  if (note === "C") {
    return (
      <React.Fragment key={note} >
        <li>{note}</li>
        <li}>{note}#</li>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  return (
    <li key={note}>{note}</li>
  );
})}
```